# JavaScript - Merge 2 array of object based on key value

Tags: javascript

I have this 2 array :

```
let filterdata = [
    {
        "value": "item",
        "text": "additional_image_link",
        "custom": null,
        "updates": true,
        "removes": true
    },
    {
        "value": "url",
        "text": "adwords_grouping",
        "custom": null,
        "updates": true,
        "removes": true
    },
    {
        "value": "campaign_id",
        "text": "id",
        "custom": null,
        "updates": true,
        "removes": true
    }
];

let newdata = [
    {
        "value": "item",
        "text": "do_not_import",
        "custom": null,
        "updates": true,
        "removes": true
    },
    {
        "value": "url",
        "text": "do_not_import",
        "custom": null,
        "updates": true,
        "removes": true
    },
    {
        "value": "campaign_id",
        "text": "do_not_import",
        "custom": null,
        "updates": true,
        "removes": true
    },
    {
        "value": "campaign_url",
        "text": "do_not_import",
        "custom": null,
        "updates": true,
        "removes": true
    },
    {
        "value": "luck",
        "text": "do_not_import",
        "custom": null,
        "updates": true,
        "removes": true
    },
    {
        "value": "okay",
        "text": "do_not_import",
        "custom": null,
        "updates": true,
        "removes": true
    },
    {
        "value": "nope",
        "text": "do_not_import",
        "custom": null,
        "updates": true,
        "removes": true
    },
    {
        "value": "brand",
        "text": "do_not_import",
        "custom": null,
        "updates": true,
        "removes": true
    }
]
```

I want to marged this 2 array and the output should be like that:

```
[
    {
        "value": "item",
        "text": "additional_image_link",
        "custom": null,
        "updates": true,
        "removes": true
    },
    {
        "value": "url",
        "text": "adwords_grouping",
        "custom": null,
        "updates": true,
        "removes": true
    },
    {
        "value": "campaign_id",
        "text": "id",
        "custom": null,
        "updates": true,
        "removes": true
    },
    {
        "value": "campaign_url",
        "text": "do_not_import",
        "custom": null,
        "updates": true,
        "removes": true
    },
    {
        "value": "luck",
        "text": "do_not_import",
        "custom": null,
        "updates": true,
        "removes": true
    },
    {
        "value": "okay",
        "text": "do_not_import",
        "custom": null,
        "updates": true,
        "removes": true
    },
    {
        "value": "nope",
        "text": "do_not_import",
        "custom": null,
        "updates": true,
        "removes": true
    },
    {
        "value": "brand",
        "text": "do_not_import",
        "custom": null,
        "updates": true,
        "removes": true
    }
]
```

I am trying this :

```
let final = newdata.filter( ( item, index ) => {
    return item.text === 'do_not_import' && filterdata.hasOwnProperty( 'text' ) !== 'do_not_import' ;
});

console.log( final )
```

but no luck :(

**Merged Logic:**

You can see that `filterdata` `value` key is exist in `newdata` but in newdata `text` value is `do_not_import` and in filterdata `text` value is **not** `do_not_import`.

so in that case, its should remove the those `filterdata` from the `newdata`.

Comment: Can you explain the merging logic? Are you trying to merge two arrays together, or trying to merge the objects within the arrays together (if so, is there some key that determines if two objects merge?)

Comment: @NickParsons I have updated my question and I have written my best to explanation. Please have a look.

Comment: Also, can you explain why you're using `filter`, which is used to filter an array for elements that don't match your criteria, and can't generate new kinds of data, only "keep what you already have, or throw things away"?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I have no idea how to get the result and I was trying.

Comment: There's a lot of questions on SO, if you google for "Javascript merge two arrays of objects on key" you get _so_ many results, including loads of Stackoverflow answers =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the below working snippet

```js
let filterdata = [
    {
        "value": "item",
        "text": "additional_image_link",
        "custom": null,
        "updates": true,
        "removes": true
    },
    {
        "value": "url",
        "text": "adwords_grouping",
        "custom": null,
        "updates": true,
        "removes": true
    },
    {
        "value": "campaign_id",
        "text": "id",
        "custom": null,
        "updates": true,
        "removes": true
    }
];

let newdata = [
    {
        "value": "item",
        "text": "do_not_import",
        "custom": null,
        "updates": true,
        "removes": true
    },
    {
        "value": "url",
        "text": "do_not_import",
        "custom": null,
        "updates": true,
        "removes": true
    },
    {
        "value": "campaign_id",
        "text": "do_not_import",
        "custom": null,
        "updates": true,
        "removes": true
    },
    {
        "value": "campaign_url",
        "text": "do_not_import",
        "custom": null,
        "updates": true,
        "removes": true
    },
    {
        "value": "luck",
        "text": "do_not_import",
        "custom": null,
        "updates": true,
        "removes": true
    },
    {
        "value": "okay",
        "text": "do_not_import",
        "custom": null,
        "updates": true,
        "removes": true
    },
    {
        "value": "nope",
        "text": "do_not_import",
        "custom": null,
        "updates": true,
        "removes": true
    },
    {
        "value": "brand",
        "text": "do_not_import",
        "custom": null,
        "updates": true,
        "removes": true
    }
]

let combinedArr = [...filterdata, ...newdata ];
let result = Array.from(new Set(combinedArr.map(a => (a.value))))
.map(val => { return combinedArr.find(item => (item.value === val)); });
console.log(result)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Its exactly what I want but can it be more simplyfied?

Comment: Yes, probably will post it in some time. Meanwhile now that you have this solution you can also try to optimize it